# How do I fix popup iframe to avoid same domain policy?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, same-origin-policy

I created a lightbox, with an iframe feature to load external websites. Some of the websites being iframed in the lightbox load, such as my own site www.scriptsconnect.com, as well as www.w3schools.com. But sites like google.com and yahoo.com don't load, and the error being thrown in my browser is the same domain policy.

A JSFiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/WZrmL/

Below is all my code. If someone could help me with an approach that would work to get around the same origin policy, I'd really appreciate it. Perhaps my approach is what is throwing the SOP?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-us" lang="en-us">
<head>
<title>SC Popup</title>
<meta charset="windows-1252">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }

.clear { clear: both; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 0; height: 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; overflow: hidden; }

/* Backdrop */
div.popupbackdrop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999998;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
    }

/* Popup */
#scpopup {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 999999;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    color: #000;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
    }
    #scpopupouter {
        padding: 15px;
        height: 100%;
        border: 15px solid #000;
        border: 15px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
        background-color: #fff;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);

        -webkit-border-radius:  6px;
        -moz-border-radius:     6px;
        border-radius:          6px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
        -moz-box-shadow:    0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
        box-shadow:         0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
        }
        #scpopupinner {
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
            }

            /* Popup Title/Subtitle */
            #scpopuptitle,
            #scpopupsubtitle {
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 50;
                width: 100%;
                font-size: 13px;
                text-align: center;
                }
                #scpopuptitle {
                    top: -60px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    }
                #scpopupsubtitle {
                    bottom: -60px;
                    }

            #scpopupholder {
                height: 100%;
                }
                #scpopupcontent {
                    height: 100%;
                    color: #131313;
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
                    font-size: 13px;
                    font-style: normal;
                    font-weight: normal;
                    line-height: 15px;
                    text-align: left;
                    }
                    #scpopupcontent iframe {
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                        border: 0 none;
                        }

</style>
<script>
(function($){
    $.fn.scpopup = function(options){

        var defaults = {

            // Settings Variables
            linkType        : "iframe",     // iframe, inline, html, image
            scWidth         : "65%",        // Width of popup container (in px, % or auto)
            scHeight        : "auto",       // Height of popup container (in px, % or auto)
            popupMaxWidth   : "700px;",     // Max width of popup container (in px, % or auto)
            popupMaxHeight  : "auto",       // Max width of popup container (in px, % or auto)
            popupTheme      : "test",       // Popup theme name (is an additional class added to parent)
            activeClass     : "active",     // Class name to use for active elements
            popupPosition   : "fixed",      // absolute, fixed
            effectOpen      : "",           // Popup opening effect
            effectClose     : "",           // Popup closing effect
            htmlContent     : "<h2>Title</h2><p>This content will go into the popup.</p>" // Must set linkType to html
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        // Functions to Specify Width and Height of Popup
        function scpopupWidth(scW) {
            $('#scpopup').css({'position' : options.popupPosition, 'margin-left' : '-' + scW/2 + 'px'});
        }
        function scpopupHeight(scH) {
            $('#scpopup').css({'position' : options.popupPosition, 'margin-top' : '-' + scH/2 + 'px'});
        }

        // Append Backdrop and Content Container
        $('div.popupbackdrop').remove();
        $('body').append('<div class="popupbackdrop"></div>');
        $('body').append('<div id="scpopup" class="scpopup"><div id="scpopupouter"><div id="scpopupinner"><div id="scpopuptitle"></div><div id="scpopupsubtitle"></div><div id="scpopupholder"><div id="scpopupcontent"></div><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div><div class="clear"></div></div>');

        // Set Width and Height of Outer Container
        $('#scpopup').width(options.scWidth).height(options.scHeight).addClass(options.popupTheme);

        $(this).addClass('scpopuplink');

        // Click Event: Open
        $(this).on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            // Margin/Width/Height for Popup
            scpopupWidth($('#scpopup').width());
            scpopupHeight($('#scpopup').height());

            // Setting Body/HTML tags to 100% width and height
            $('body', 'html').css({'width' : '100%', 'height' : '100%'});
            $('body').addClass('scpopupactive');

            // Transitions
            $('div.popupbackdrop').fadeIn(150).addClass(options.activeClass);
            $('#scpopup').fadeIn(300).addClass(options.activeClass);

            // Empty Title/Subtitle Holders on Click
            $('#scpopuptitle, #scpopupsubtitle').empty();

            // Load Title/Subtitles on Click
            $('<span></span>').text($(this).attr('title')).appendTo('#scpopuptitle');
            $('<span></span>').text($(this).attr('alt')).appendTo('#scpopupsubtitle');

            // Link Type (linkType)
            if(options.linkType == 'iframe'){
                $('#scpopupcontent').empty().append(
                    $('<iframe>', {src: this.href})
                );
                //$('#scpopupcontent').empty().append('<iframe src="' + this.href + '"></iframe>');
            }else if(options.linkType == 'inline'){
                //alert('inline');
            }else if(options.linkType == 'html') {
                $('#scpopupcontent').empty().append(options.htmlContent);
            }else if(options.linkType == 'image') {
                //alert('image');
            }
        });

        // Click Event: Close
        $('div.popupbackdrop').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $('body').removeClass('scpopupactive');
            $(this).delay(50).fadeOut(300).removeClass(options.activeClass);
            $('#scpopup').delay(25).fadeOut(150).removeClass(options.activeClass);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.itemlink').scpopup({ scHeight : "500px" });
    $('.htmlcontent').scpopup({
        linkType        : "html",
        scHeight        : "350px",
        htmlContent     : "<h2>HTML Content Title</h2><p>This content will go into the popup. This content shows up in the popup only if linkType is set to html.</p>"
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="itemlink" target="_blank" title="Google Title" alt="Google Subtitle">Google</a>
    <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" class="itemlink" target="_blank" title="Yahoo Title" alt="Yahoo Subtitle">Yahoo</a>
    <a href="http://www.w3schools.com" class="itemlink" target="_blank" title="W3Schools Title" alt="W3Schools Subtitle">W3Schools</a>
    <a href="http://www.scriptsconnect.com" class="itemlink" target="_blank" title="ScriptsConnect Title" alt="ScriptsConnect Subtitle">ScriptsConnect</a>
    <a href="#" class="htmlcontent" target="_blank">html content</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, lightbox plugins like Colorbox ( `http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/` ) allow google.com to be loaded in their lightbox. Any idea how they achieve this if it is indeed possible? I'll have to download Colorbox and test it later today to see if it is possible.

Comment: I got the latest version of colorbox and tested, and it isn't able to load google.com either. Oh well. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the reason is google returns:

**X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN**

you can read informations about it in this specification:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

If I understand it right, when you recieve **X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN**, you are able open this window in IFrame but only on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Enterting Cross-domain websites is a real security concern.

With that said, there are proxy sites that will allow you to load websites that don't allow cross-domain

e.g
http://www.corsproxy.com/

so http://www.corsproxy.com/google.com will work anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Sites like Google and Yahoo have the [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) set on `SAMEORIGIN`, which means unless you're Google or Yahoo, you're not allowed to load the website in an iframe. You can try curl and curl the page you're looking for and display the results or use some sort of proxy.